# How can I get button element below the div floats?

Tags: css

How can I get the **"Run"** button below the divs?

[image]

Here is the code: http://jsbin.com/ehurit/10/edit

Same code copy-pasted below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div.boxes { background:yellow; border:1px solid #AAA; width:80px; height:80px; margin:0 5px; float:left; }
  div.colored { background:green; }
  .clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
} 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="boxes"></div>
  <div class="boxes" id="mover"></div>
  <div class="boxes"></div>     
  <button class="clearfix" id="run" >Run</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `display: block` and `clear: both` in your `.clearfix` CSS class

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dC7GL/)

**Update**: I just checked again and you should probably set the clearfix around your floating divs like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dC7GL/1/

Answer (score 3):

Change your style

```
.clearfix {
      clear:both;
}
```

Then above the button add a div tag and apply the clear fix style it will push the button down below the boxes

```
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <button id="run" >Run</button>
```